# Java Socket：How does the client determine whether the socket has been disconnected?

Tags: java, sockets

If I close the server socket, how does the client know that the Socket has been disconnected?
For instance, look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKuvs.jpg) where the reply is null when the socket was disconnected.

Comment: When the peer shuts down the output side of their socket you will observe an EOF on the InputStream you obtained from `Socket.getInputStream()`, after reading the the pending data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a class implementing `Runnable` somewhere in your code that acts as the incoming-message-reader in your client code? Something like this, perhaps:

```
 public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            String message;
            try{
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println("read " + message);
                    incoming.append(message + "\n");
                    //incoming is the TextBox where messages are displayed, in this case
                }
            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

When the socket gets disconnected, an exception will be thrown when you read a message, and the control flow will shift to the `catch` block. There, I for instance decide to close the client. You could change it to whatever you want to do.

It's hard to comment further without a minimal reproducible code of your work.